# Convert Integer to Unsigned Long

Tags: c, sockets, int, unsigned-integer

Trying to use the function `htonl()` for a program that sends an init message to a server, along with an integer value, say 5. However, `htonl()` needs the following *`uint32_t` integer hostlong*

How can I convert 5 to an unsigned integer?

Comment: Can you please accept Keith's answer so I can delete mine? It's misleading I shouldn't have answered that.

Comment: I mean the answer has nothing wrong, it's just that in your case you really don't need the cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `htonl` function is declared in `<arpa/inet.h>`.  Assuming you have a proper `#include` for that header:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>`
```

the declaration

```
uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);
```

will be visible, so the compiler knows the expected argument type and the result type.

If you want to pass the value `5` to the `htonl` function, just pass it:

```
uint32_t result = htonl(5);
```

The constant `5` is of type `int`. The compiler will generate an implicit conversion from `int` to `uint32_t`. (It's likely the conversion won't actually have to do anything.)

If the value `5` is stored in an `int` object, it's the same thing:

```
int n = 5;
uint32_t result = htonl(n);
```

No explicit conversion (cast) is necessary.

(Incidentally, there's an important distinction between "`int`" and "integer". There are a number of integer types, including `short`, `unsigned long`, `uint32_t`, and so forth. `int` is the name of one of those types. An `unsigned long` value *is* an integer.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a typecasting operation - something along the lines of

```
int foo = 5;
htonl((unsigned int) foo);
```

Comment: @iharob The comment about `-5` does not tie to this answer.  suggest Elaborating your thought.

Comment: Assuming a prototype of `htonl` is visible, the cast merely does the same conversion that would have been done implicitly.

Comment: @Keith Thompson With `uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);`, casting to `(unsigned int)` is typically the same as calling with no cast, yet would be different if `int/unsigned` is 16-bit.  Consider `int foo = -1;`

Comment: @chux: Good point! The cast is not only unnecessary, but potentially harmful. (Casting to `uint32_t` would be merely unnecessary.)

Answer (score 0):

`htonl(3)` - **Linux man page**

> ```
> uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);
> ```
>
> The `htonl()` function converts the unsigned integer hostlong from host byte order to network byte order.

So all you need to do is to cast your variable

```
uint32_t x = 5;
htonl(x);
```

Comment: "cast your variable"??  I see an assignment, but no cast.

Comment: @chux: Which is good, because no cast is necessary. (To clarify, an implicit conversion is not a cast; the term "cast" refers only to the explicit operator.)